# Exporting Bulk DNS query for A, CNAME, NS and MX record using Powershell Resolve-DNS as multiline instead of ; delimiter?

Tags: powershell

I wonder if the below Powershell script can be modified so the multiple DNS entries like:
TXT and NS records, can be output into multiple lines instead of one line with ; as delimiter?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
   [String[]]$Name,
   [String]$Server
)
   Begin {
      $splat = @{
         ErrorAction = 'Stop'
      }
      If ($Server) {
         $splat['Server'] = $Server
      }
   }
   Process {
      $Name | ForEach-Object {
         $out = $_ | Select-Object -Property @{n='Name'; e={$_}}, SOA, A, CNAME, MX, TXT, NS
         $splat['Name'] = $_
         Try {
            $out.SOA = Resolve-DnsName -Type SOA @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'SOA'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PrimaryServer
         } Catch {
            $out.SOA = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         Try {
            $out.A = (Resolve-DnsName -Type A @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'A'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress | Sort-Object -Property @{e={[Version]$_}}) -join ', '
         } Catch {
            $out.A = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         Try {
            $out.CNAME = Resolve-DnsName -Type CNAME @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'CNAME'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameHost
         } Catch {
            $out.CNAME = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         Try {
            $out.MX = (Resolve-DnsName -Type MX @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'MX'} | Sort-Object -Property Preference, NameExchange | ForEach-Object {"$($_.NameExchange):$($_.Preference)"}) -join "`n"
         } Catch {
            $out.MX = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         Try {
            $out.TXT = (Resolve-DnsName -Type TXT @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'TXT'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Strings | ForEach-Object {"'$($_)'"}) -join "`n"
         } Catch {
            $out.TXT = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         Try {
            $out.NS = (Resolve-DnsName -Type NS @splat | Where-Object {$_.QueryType -eq 'NS'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameHost | Sort-Object) -join "`n"
         } Catch {
            $out.NS = "<$($_.Exception.Message)>"
         }
         $out
      }
   }

Name    SOA A   CNAME   MX  TXT NS
domain.com  ns-2022.awsdns-60.co.uk 13.228.112.135      mx.domain.com:10    google-site-verification=zlpN6bg9OaBJVw4Lv4-1fZ2wHekVqEnEGBXwuonNpBM', 'v=spf1 ip4:38.113.1.0/24 ip4:38.113.20.0/24 ip4:12.45.243.128/26 ip4:65.254.224.0/19 include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.qualtrics.com -all', 'google-site-verification=M2Ehy1mb_Yh-Z57igzRDXPY35c5nNsYmI_l3B6D9zZs'   ns-1250.awsdns-28.org, ns-166.awsdns-20.com, ns-2022.awsdns-60.co.uk, ns-683.awsdns-21.net
domain.com
```

So the TXT and NS entry in the above can be exported one per line items?

but it becomes like below with `n:

```
Name    SOA A   CNAME   MX  TXT
domain.com  ns-2022.awsdns-60.co.uk 13.228.112.135      mx.domain.com:10    'google-site-verification=zlpN6bg9OaBJVw4Lv4-1fZ2wHekVqEnEGBXwuonNpBM'`n 'v=spf1 ip4:38.113.1.0/24 ip4:38.113.20.0/24 ip4:12.45.243.128/26 ip4:65.254.224.0/19 include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.qualtrics.com -all'`n 'google-site-verification=M2Ehy1mb_Yh-Z57igzRDXPY35c5nNsYmI_l3B6D9zZs'
```

Expected output:

```
Name    Type    Values
domain.com  A   13.228.112.135
domain.com  NS  ns1.domain.com
domain.com  NS  ns2.domain.com
domain.com  MX  mx.domain.com:10
domain.com  MX  mx2.domain.com:20
domain.com  TXT     value1
domain.com  TXT     value2
domain.com  TXT     fdsfssg4534
domain.com  TXT     54323gfdbdb
domain.com  TXT     452353gfdfsdsd
domain.com  CNAME   www
```

more like the DNS entry in DNS console.

Comment: How about `$out | fl` ?

Comment: You will need to change your join from `-join ','` to ```-join "`n"```.

Comment: sadly it is not working as per updated result above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [nice module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DnsClient-PS/1.0.0) you can install and combined with the following function, is very close to what you describe. Hopefully it's helpful.

```
Install-Module DNSClient-PS -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Import-Module DNSClient-PS


function Get-DNSRecord {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String[]]$Name,

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [String]$Server
    )

    Begin
    {
        $params = @{
            ErrorAction   = 'Stop'
            ErrorVariable = 'err'
        }
        If ($Server) {
            $params += @{
                 NameServer = $Server
            }
        }
    }

    Process
    {
        foreach($nm in $name)
        {
        
            'SOA', 'A', 'CNAME', 'MX', 'TXT', 'NS' | Foreach-Object {
                $type = $_
                try
                {
                    Resolve-Dns -Query $nm -QueryType $type @params | select -expand answers
                }
                catch
                {
                    write-warning $_.exception.message
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

Get-DNSRecord stackoverflow.com 9.9.9.9
```

Output

```
DomainName         TimeToLive RecordClass RecordType RecordData                                                                                      
----------         ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------                                                                                      
stackoverflow.com. 900        IN          SOA        ns-1033.awsdns-01.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400                   
stackoverflow.com. 3380       IN          A          151.101.65.69                                                                                   
stackoverflow.com. 3380       IN          A          151.101.193.69                                                                                  
stackoverflow.com. 3380       IN          A          151.101.129.69                                                                                  
stackoverflow.com. 3380       IN          A          151.101.1.69                                                                                    
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          MX         10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.                                                                     
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          MX         1 aspmx.l.google.com.                                                                           
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          MX         5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.                                                                      
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          MX         5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.                                                                      
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          MX         10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.                                                                     
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "google-site-verification=o3EMam8yBGo1yEjyybIiZcOunGHOQKpo8JmOtp9n1BU"                          
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "google-site-verification=rdWtMbplKjbRHGr2dNONfwkqithlUvjr3u6i8QEz_mo"                          
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "v=spf1 ip4:198.252.206.0/24 include:_spf1.stackoverflow.com ~all"                              
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "MS=ms52592611"                                                                                 
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "atlassian-domain-verification=byLeZgl3MIcfOqwWuMhq8Fhr/1zem/jIaouJegvDZbBKUU5OqhwDjdpkyYg5CTzm"
stackoverflow.com. 300        IN          TXT        "google-site-verification=ctogLnZNAdc_CXq8yOhODMLpmugGynjxKecKHDz4oL8"                          
stackoverflow.com. 172800     IN          NS         ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.                                                                          
stackoverflow.com. 172800     IN          NS         ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.                                                                  
stackoverflow.com. 172800     IN          NS         ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.                                                                  
stackoverflow.com. 172800     IN          NS         ns-358.awsdns-44.com.
```